# the onStop() not excute immediately after onPause() has done?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Once I finish the activity,the method of onPause() excute immediately.but the method of onstop() coming with delay.Just about after 10 sec,the onstop() can be excute.

why and how can I solve it?

Result:

[image]

Comment: are you sure you do not do anything time-intensive in your onpause??

Comment: the target activity can be finish normally from the another activity.It happens when I goto the target activity from the one which the style same as the dialog.can you understand my meaning?

Comment: DO u able to find solution or rca of above problem ? I am facing similar issue as u